# rails c : [FATAL] failed to allocate memory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, osx-lion

I am getting this error when trying to run my rails app  :

[FATAL] failed to allocate memory

This is on a new mac book air with lion. It used to run ok, I don't really know what I changed...

I also get this error when doing rake db:drop :

```
[BUG] Segmentation fault
ruby 1.9.2p180 (2011-02-18 revision 30909) [x86_64-darwin11.0.1]

-- control frame ----------
c:0001 p:0000 s:0002 b:0002 l:000498 d:000498 TOP   
---------------------------

-- C level backtrace information -------------------------------------------

[NOTE]
You may have encountered a bug in the Ruby interpreter or extension libraries.
Bug reports are welcome.
For details: http://www.ruby-lang.org/bugreport.html

Abort trap: 6
```

someone knows how I can fix this? Thanks!

Comment: I don't know why it caused this error , but the cause seems to have been that my locale was not set.... now it works....

Comment: I would report that as a bug though.

Comment: @David I'm getting the error on one of my machines when I try to run my rails app, and when I run rake db commands. Which is strange cause its working seamlessly on two other machines and the one with the issue is a fresh system install. Same OSX version as both of the machines that are working fine. Where would I go to set my locale?